# How to fix selenium calls to click on a button (in python)?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click on a WEB button in selenium, but this is more complicated than it sounds. Here is the python code I am using (inside a unit-test):

```
def search(self, key, value):
    """To return an element with the given key-value pair"""
    elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@%s]"%key)
    for element in elements:
        if element.get_attribute(key) == value:
            return element
    return None

def test1(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    self.driver.get("https://www.swisscom.ch/de/privatkunden.html")
    button = self.search("data-tracking-title", "Mobile_Handys & Tablets")
    element = self.driver.find_element_by_id("scs-pageheader-navigation-link-1")
    hover = ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(element)
    hover.perform()
    button.click()

    hrefs = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='gridProduct10247118']")
```

with the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='gridProduct10247118']"}
```

Well, the error makes sense, because selenium does not seem to have clicked on the `button`-element I searched for above.

Why is selenium not performing the 'click' on that button? What do I miss here?

P.S. Sometimes it does not work at all, the `button` is `None` in that case. One then needs to repeat the whole test UNCHANGED and maybe it will work then. How to fix that? I tried to increase the wait time, but it did not help either...

Comment: Try including the click within your ActionChain?
`ActionCahins(self.drvier).move_to_element(element).click(self.search("data-tracking-title", "Mobile_Handys & Tablets")).perform()`

Comment: No does not work: `Message: Offset within element cannot be scrolled into view: (0, 0`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to re-arrange some of the code lines! The correct order is:

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_id("scs-pageheader-navigation-link-1")
hover = ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(element)#.click(self.search("data-tracking-title", "Mobile_Handys & Tablets")).perform()
hover.perform()
button = self.search("data-tracking-title", "Mobile_Handys & Tablets")
button.click()
```

My probable explanation: First, one must perform the 'hover' action and ***then*** find the button to click on. It looks like the original button has its 'hidden' attribute still set after the 'hover' action...